# To burnate, or not to burnate?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have found a couple of tags that look too much like meta-tags:

- [computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer): has been used once, where the question is also tagged [zx-spectrum](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zx-spectrum). (Retagged)
- [color](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color): both times used with [display](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display): maybe [color-display](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-display) would be better? (Retagged)

There are probably more of these on the site, and more will definitely be created in the future. I know we are only just out of private beta, but it is often easier to sort out such problems whilst they are small.

In situations like these, what should we do?

Answer (score 5):

Burnination is probably [unnecessary at the moment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/1438). But I could see an argument for making [computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer) an [intrinsic tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62183/1438). If it comes up again, please let me know so that I can make the change.

[color](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) is potentially ambiguous, so [color-display](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-display) seems like a better choice. My guess is that most people mean something-other-than-monochrome monitor/graphics card when they use "color" in the context of this site. So a synonym (with [color-display](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-display) as the master) seems the right thing to do.

Comment: The tag computer may seem intrinsic, but for a machine like the TI-99/4A for example, it might mean something specific.  The TI is a keyboard computer like so many from the era, but connects to a Peripheral Expansion Box (PEB) that looks like a desktop Intel PC. A question might refer to the computer itself (TI called it the console).  Would ti-99-console be a better tag in that case?

Answer (score 3):

The two you mention are meta tags and unnecessary.

We should nip them in the bud before they become a nuisance.  Retag the questions and let the Roomba do its thing.